# Adding an annotation to mkmap, but want to remove part of the annotation but it won't remove

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I create an annotation, which contains several elements textbubble and pin. I turn the bubble on when I show annotation, but later I want to shut the bubble off and leave the annotation.

Here are my two methods.  The add subview works, but remove subview does not.

```
-(void)hideETACountdown {
self.etaView.hidden = YES;
[self.etaView removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void)showETACountdown {

self.etaView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-34, -97, 89, 59)];
UIImageView *bg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"WaitBubble_backgroundandshadow.png"]];
[self.etaView addSubview:bg];
UILabel *minLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(7, 24, 42, 21)];
minLabel.text = @"min";
minLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
minLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

self.etaLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 4, 30, 27)];
self.etaLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22];
self.etaLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
self.etaLabel.text = @"";

[self.etaView addSubview:minLabel];
[self.etaView addSubview:self.etaLabel];

[self addSubview:self.etaView];

self.etaView.hidden = NO;
}

- (id) initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
if (self = [super initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {


    self.canShowCallout = YES;
    self.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];

    self.innerImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
    self.innerImage.frame = CGRectMake(-15, -38, 32, 39);

    [self addSubview:self.innerImage];

    if(self.showETA) {

        [NSNotificationCenter addUniqueObserver:self
                                       selector:@selector(handleEtaTimeUpdate:)
                                           name:kEtaUpdate
                                         object:nil];
        [self showETACountdown];

    }

}
return self;
}
```

// UPDATE /////

There seems to be some confusion. This code above is not in the viewController that holds my mkmap, but rather the code inside my custom annotation. Further, I don't want to hide or show the entire annotation based on selecting or deselecting. The self.etaView is custom view which is just part of the annotation. My annotation consists of a custom map pin and an eta bubble. Once the ETA is counted down to 0, I want to remove the bubble (aka self.etaView), but the annotation (map pin) needs to stay on the map the entire time. I just want to hide the ETA bubble.

I am using the proper addAnnotation methods, in the proper way, in my viewController that holds my mkmap. Again, this code above is inside my custom annotation and I want my custom annotation to be responsible for removing its own elements, NOT removing itself from the map.

Answer (score 2):

Come on, why using this weird logics with addSubView and removeFromSuperView. MKMapView is built to support "datasource" for pins. I dunno what kind of view you are trying to acheive but this `CGRectMake(-34, -97, 89, 59)` looks awful.  So please, use method:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

This way you will have no difficulties managing the annotation using method

```
- (void)deselectAnnotation:(id < MKAnnotation >)annotation animated:(BOOL)animated
```

For example:

```
[mapView deselectAnnotation:[mapView.selectedAnnotations objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

Comment: yes, don't mess with the view hierarchy directly here... use the provided framework methods

Comment: to add/remove annotation call addAnotation / removeAnnotation

Comment: Settle down guys.  The code above is not in my controller that manages the map. This is code in my annotation. Thus the - (id) initWithAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier  I am using the viewForAnnotation method in my viewcontroller that runs the class. Also please don't assume deselectAnnotation is when I want to remove the subview of the annotation. I never want to remove the annotation once shown. I also hide and show self.etaView via code not screen touches. And self.etaView is not the entire annotation just one view element of it.

Comment: I know this code is a custom annotation class. If you ran into this issue you've checked everything for sure, but maybe the etaview is nil? what is it's frame? it just does not react to removeFromSuperView: ? You might want to try out the method described in this [class](https://github.com/akshay1188/CustomAnnotation/blob/master/CustomAnnotation/CustomAnnotationView.m) and remove it directly from calloutview

Answer (score 0):

The method to remove the bubble was getting called, but it just wasn't getting removed?  So what I have done is create notification listener on my annotation and post a notification when I want it removed and it removes it.  Not sure why it doesn't just work by calling an instance method?

Anyway, notifications solved it. Need to move on so I can launch the app.